# Add vertical line between acronyms and their meaning

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm trying to get a vertical line between acronyms and their meaning. Basically I want to copy the style as shown in the image below:

[image: Desired outcome]

I have created a minimum working example with my progress thus far. I think using a longtable will do the trick but I haven't figured out how to do it. Any help would be appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nopostdot, nogroupskip, style=super, acronym, nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}} 
\renewcommand*{\glossarypreamble}{\vspace{\baselineskip}} 


\makeglossaries

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}
\newacronym{lcm}{LCM}{Least Common Multiple}
\newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}
\newacronym{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym{un}{UN}{United Nations}

\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\glsaddall

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the `super` style – or rather define a new style where you redefine the essential part (for this I looked up the original definition in the file `glossaries-super.sty`):

```
\newglossarystyle{superline}{%
  \setglossarystyle{super}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\tablehead{}\tabletail{}%
     \begin{supertabular}{l|p{\glsdescwidth}}}%
    {\end{supertabular}}%
}
\setglossarystyle{superline}
```

Using this in your MWE we get:

[image]

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nopostdot, nogroupskip, acronym, nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}} 
\renewcommand*{\glossarypreamble}{\vspace{\baselineskip}} 

\newglossarystyle{superline}{%
  \setglossarystyle{super}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\tablehead{}\tabletail{}%
     \begin{supertabular}{l|p{\glsdescwidth}}}%
    {\end{supertabular}}%
}
\setglossarystyle{superline}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}
\newacronym{lcm}{LCM}{Least Common Multiple}
\newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}
\newacronym{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym{un}{UN}{United Nations}

\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\glsaddall

\end{document}
```